# MSQL JOIN: I cant show a list of categories

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

Im trying to show in a list of "specs" all the "cars" of the table depending on the specs table value it receives.

Tables:

**cars:**

```
dcar: 1 / width:30 / length:10 / weight:300
idcar: 2 / width:20 / length:12 / weight:210
idcar: 3 / width:20 / length:21 / weight:230
idcar: 4 / width:40 / length:11 / weight:210
```

**specs table:**

```
idspec:1 spec:width
idspec:2 spec:weight
idspec:3 spec:length
```

**And the output would be:**

```
Width
car-1 width-30
car-2 width-20
car-3 width-20
car-4 width-40


Weight
car-1 weight-300
car-2 weight-210
car-3 weight-230
car-4 weight-210

Length
car-1 length-10
car-2 length-12
car-3 length-21
car-4 length-11
```

Is OK my query? I would like to use it in a while or foreach (php)

```
$resultjoin = mysqli_query($connecDB,"SELECT specs.idspec, specs.spec, cars.idcar FROM (specs) LEFT JOIN cars ON cars.idcar = specs.idspec");
```

Thank you!

Comment: remove the single quotes

Comment: I tried but that's not the problem :/ Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done!

```
$resultlast = mysqli_query($connecDB,"select * from cars order by (case id when $idcar then 0 else id end), name asc");
```

and

```
$rows = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultlast)){
        $rows[] = $row;
    }

    while($rowspec = mysqli_fetch_array($resultspec)){
        echo '<div id="'.$rowspec["name"].'">';

            foreach($rows as $row){ 
                $car = stripslashes($row['name']);
                echo '<div id="'.$rowspec["name"].'">' . $car . '</div>';
            }

        echo '</div>';
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this

There is mistake in your table design. There another table in between spec and car. Such as car_apec_value which will have carid, specid, value.

By joining this three table you will get your desire result e.g.

```
$resultjoin = mysqli_query($connecDB,"SELECT 'cars'.'idcar', 'specs'.'spec' FROM cars LEFT JOIN car_apec_value ON cars'.idcar = 'car_apec_value'.'carid' where specs.specid = car_apec_value.specid AND specs.specid='1'");
```

Answer (score 2):

I looks like you are trying to unpivot your table.  If so, your query is quite a bit off.

```
SELECT c.idcar, 'width' as which, width as value
FROM cars c
union all
SELECT c.idcar, 'length' as which, length as value
FROM cars c
union all
SELECT c.idcar, 'weight' as which, weight as value
FROM cars c
```

Comment: +1  `UNION` will suffice since the rows are for sure distinct

Comment: Wow THANKS, and is it possible to put that in a while or foreach?

Comment: @santyas . . . Yes.  But php coding is not my expertise, so I'll leave that for someone more knowledgeable.

Comment: @Stephen . . . Thank you for fixing the alias.  However, you should be in the habit of using `union all` rather than `union`.  `union` does duplicate elimination, which is often extra work when not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT('car-',idcar),
    CONCAT('width-',width)
FROM
    cars
UNION
SELECT
    CONCAT('car-',idcar),
    CONCAT('weight-',weight)
FROM
    cars
UNION
SELECT
    CONCAT('car-',idcar),
    CONCAT('length-',length)
FROM
    cars
```

Comment: ok THANKS but I ask the same. Is it possible to put that in a while or foreach?

Comment: @santyas what do you mean? to execute it each time in a loop ? what is the final purpose?

Comment: Yes, In my question the output is the final purpose. In a "while" show all specs, and inside having a foreach with all the cars and the specific value of the "while" on each car.

Comment: Example:
`<h1>WIDTH</h1>
<li>car-1 width:20</li>
<li>car-2 width:15</li>

<h1>HEIGHT</h1>
<li>car-1 height:20</li>
<li>car-2 height:15</li>
`

Comment: you just need to exec the query once and after loop through the results and build the list like above

Answer (score 1):

So as i understand you need request to select all the cars in any case. But selected data fields depends on "idspec" you give. I mean if you give idspec=2, you want to get:

```
car-1 weight-300
car-2 weight-210
car-3 weight-230
car-4 weight-210
```

In this case you can just do 2 requests:

```
SELECT spec FROM specs WHERE idspec = $idspec
this will give you needed field from "specs" table, lets call it $spec.
SELECT CONCAT('car-', idcar), CONCAT('$spec-', $spec) FROM cars
```

this will select needed info

Comment: Thank you. I solved it with while and foreach. I wrote above my example.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `'` with ` can work ! Try it !